# VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED when trying to create a Windows 8 image in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, windows-8-preview

I'm trying to create a VirtualBox image of Windows 8 Consumer Preview. I did exactly what was said in [this tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-windows-8-on-virtualbox), but at the step "Now navigate to the Windows 8 developer build ISO file that you downloaded and select it" I get the following error:

> Could not get the storage format. (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)

I also get this if I use the regular wizard. I'm using VirtualBox version 4.1.16 on Windows 7. It happens with both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows 8 as the guest OS.

Answer (score 2):

Have you verified that the ISO image file containing the install for Windows 8 Consumer Preview has no errors?

You can find the different ISO image files and their corresponding SHA-1 hash checksums listed on this page: 
[**Windows 8 Consumer Preview ISO images**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/download)

Microsoft provides an [**unsupported command line utility**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) whose description says it would allow you to check the Sha-1 hash for your ISO. You could also find other checksum tools by searching for them with Google.

---

Thought I would just relate what happened when I tried using my suggestion above. The `Sha-1 hash` listed on the [**Windows 8 Consumer Preview ISO images**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/download) page is

```
English 
64-bit (x64)  Sha 1 hash — 1288519C5035BCAC83CBFA23A33038CCF5522749 
32-bit (x86)  Sha 1 hash — E91ED665B01A46F4344C36D9D88C8BF78E9A1B39     
Product Key:   DNJXJ-7XBW8-2378T-X22TX-BKG7J
```

The results I got from using the `fciv` utility on the ISO images I downloaded today from that site are

```
               SHA-1
----------------------------------------
1288519c5035bcac83cbfa23a33038ccf5522749 Windows8-ConsumerPreview-64bit-English.iso
e91ed665b01a46f4344c36d9d88c8bf78e9a1b39 Windows8-ConsumerPreview-32bit-English.iso
```

The  `Sha-1 hash` for Windows 8 Consumer Preview (64-bit) which I downloaded a month ago (~ April 30), are below. I found it interesting that the hash does not match. In other words, Microsoft has apparently (silently?) changed the install ISO for Windows 8. I wonder what was changed? (And why?)

```
               SHA-1
----------------------------------------
737b33046dc5c9d4f3cf9a6f001ebf2d059afb21 Windows8-ConsumerPreview-64bit-English.old.iso
```

Comment: I redownloaded twice, and all 3 didn't give the correct SHA-1 hash. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BartBurg Answer updated. (Nothing particularly useful. Just anecdotal observations FWIW.)